# how to count the draggable elements in in a droppable area?

Tags: jquery

I have a to make a simple drag and drop game in class. I am having problems with getting it to count the number of dropped elements in the droppable area.

Can anyone assist please?

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CookbookGame</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    /* starts the counter at zero*/
    var counter=0;
    ingredients();
    /*check count amount*/
    function check()
    {
    if (counter == 4);
    { alert ("well done");
    location.href="recipe.html";
    }
    };
    function count()  /*this is the counter function*/
    {
    counter = counter + 1    
    /* this line calls count which is equal to its self and each time            count is called it will add one to itself*/

    }
    });

    function ingredients()
    { 
    /*This is the main part of the script*/
    $(".salt, .pepper, .honey").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

    $(".milk").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    $("#bowl").droppable({ 
    accept: ".milk",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    count();
    check(); 
    }
    });

    $(".egg").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    $("#bowl").droppable({
    accept: ".egg",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    count();
    check();
    }
    });

    $(".flour").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    $("#bowl").droppable({
    accept: ".flour",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    count();
    check();
    }
    });

    $(".sugar").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
    $("#bowl").droppable({
    accept: ".sugar",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
    count();
    check();
    }
    });
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">CookBook Game</div>
    <h3>The stuff you need to use to make the pancakes are on the top shelf.<br /> Be careful there are extra ingreedients there to stop you completing your task.</h3>
    <div id="pancake">Pancakes</div>
    <div id="playarea">
        <div id="tarea">
            <table id="shelf">
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="milk"><img src="images/milkjug.png" ></div></td>
                    <td><div class="egg"><img src="images/eggs.png" ></div></td>
                    <td><div class="flour"><img src="images/flour.png"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="honey"><img src="images/honey.png"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="sugar"><img src="images/sugar.png"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="salt"><img src="images/salt.png"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="pepper"><img src="images/pepper.png"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="barea">
            <div id="bowl"><img src="images/bowl.png"></div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a classname for ingredients.

```
$("#bowl .classname").length; // assuming bowl is the droppable area.
```

Comment: the bowl is the droppable area so are you meaning to change the bowl to a class from an ID ?

Comment: Nononono. :x I mean have a classname to milk,egg etc. So that when you drop the "ingredients" (lets have ingredients as their class name) .. you can just use .length() to get the number of elements with ingredients as their classname within the id bowl..